# Trying to use case to perform two subquerys (inner join)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform two different inner joins with the result from my main query, but i don't know if it's possible, i been searching and found that CASE statement can work.

I been trying with if, but i started to read documentation but isn't it's porpoise

This is my query, hope anybody can help me or show me right way.

```
SELECT * from suggestions INNER JOIN staff on suggestions.id_staff = staff.id_staff 
    (CASE
        WHEN suggestions(suggestions.for_their_area = '1')
            THEN (
                INNER JOIN areas on staff.id_area = areas.id_area
            )
        ELSE (
            INNER JOIN areas on suggestions.for_their_area = areas.id_area
        )
) WHERE suggestions.accepted = '1'
```

I expect to perform a 3 tables inner join if my value from one field equals to 1 perform the first and if that same field equals to 0 perform the second one

Comment: A case _statement_ can't be used within a query. A case _expression_ can. However, you should use AND/OR instead here.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: *"A case statement can't be used within a query"* @jarlh you right about that? `SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0
 END` is using a statement in the `CASE` and valid MySQL code, this way off JOINing is just plain wrong here.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, that's a case _expression_.

Comment: well @jarlh the case expression is in that example i've given a SELECT statement, i think i misread your first comment what you meant..  i assume we both agree that the topicstarters way off implementing a conditional JOIN is just plain wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to always join both tables, then use the Case to decide which one to use.

```
SELECT s.*,
CASE WHEN s.for_their_area='1' THEN a1.area_field ELSE a2.area_field END area_field
FROM suggestions s
INNER JOIN staff st ON s.id_staff=st.id_staff
LEFT JOIN areas a1 on st.id_area=a1.id_area
LEFT JOIN areas a2 on s.for_their_area=a2.id_area
WHERE s.accepted='1'
```

Or you could do a conditional join:

```
SELECT s.*,
a.area_field 
FROM suggestions s
INNER JOIN staff st ON s.id_staff=st.id_staff
INNER JOIN areas a ON ((s.for_their_area='1' and st.id_area=a.id_area)
OR (s.for_their_area != '1' and s.for_their_area=a.id_area))
WHERE s.accepted='1'
```

Comment: I think i didn't explain myself, i have tree tables, suggestions, staff and areas, each staff can make x number of suggestions but they can chose if the suggestion is for their area o for other one, that's were the area table enters i want to get what sugg are made for their own area and what others were made to different areas.
I say that because the second query works but it doesn't brings up the fields from staff

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i was using the wrong field at the of the query, but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Move the conditions to `ON` clauses and use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.*, st.*,
       COALESCE(a1.?, a2.?)
FROM suggestions s INNER JOIN
     staff st
     ON s.id_staff = st.id_staff LEFT JOIN
     areas a1
     ON st.id_area = a1.id_area AND
        s.for_their_area = '1' LEFT JOIN
     areas a2
     ON s.for_their_area = a2.id_area AND
        s.for_their_area <> '1'
WHERE s.accepted = '1';
```

For the columns that you want to select from `areas`, use `COALESCE()`.

You can also phrase this logic using `OR`, but that is usually a performance killer.

Comment: I couldn't make this work, thanks for your answer anyway